# Listening for DML queries on a MySQL database in Golang

Tags: mysql, sql, database, go, query-notifications

I am using [go-sql-driver/mysql](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) driver for connecting to a MySQL database in Golang. 
I wonder is there a way to listen for DML queries on the database such that the **client gets notified/triggered** when any such query occurs.
I am using the inbuilt `database/sql` package for connection.

Similar: [[1]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/283177/)